# Hotkeys not working on LXDE on Debian 12

Tags: lxde

I have an issue with some Hotkeys working fine and some other (they physically do work I know). The keybind exist in my .confif/openbox/lxde-rc.xml file and for example the screenprint works fine. I want to set the brightness and it doesn't work, same for the volume... I've checked that xbacklight, xrandr, lxhotkey... are installed.

The only way to manage brightness is with the terminal `xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness 1.3`

```
<keybind key="Print">
<action name="Execute">
<command>gnome-screenshot -i</command>
</action>
</keybind>
<!-- Launch LXRandR when Fn+Screen is pressed -->
<keybind key="XF86Display">
<action name="Execute">
<command>lxrandr</command>
</action>
</keybind>
<!-- Change the brightness -->
<keybind key="XF86MonBrightnessUp">
<action name="Execute">
<command>brightnessctl set 5%+</command>
</action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="XF86MonBrightnessDown">
<action name="Execute">
<command>brightnessctl set 5%-</command>
</action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="XF86AudioLowerVolume">
<action name="Execute">
<command>pactl -- set-sink-volume 0 -5%</command>
</action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="XF86AudioRaiseVolume">
<action name="Execute">
<command>pactl -- set-sink-volume 0 +5%</command>
</action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="W-p">
<action name="Execute">
<command>xrandr -o inverted</command>
</action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="C-F4">
<action name="Execute">
<command>xrandr -o normal</command>
</action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="XF86AudioMute">
<action name="Execute">
<command>pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle</command>
</action>
</keybind>
</keyboard>
```

Any ideas?